# Python win32com: read file from aws S3

Tags: python, excel, amazon-s3, win32com, vba

In Order to read an Excel file I am using:

```
from win32com import client as client
xlApp = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xlworkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\temp\mysheet.xlsm")
```

I want to read an Excel file from amazon S3 without saving it first on the disk:

```
file_stream = aws.s3.get_file_stream(file_name)
xlworkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file_stream)
```

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Like all computer files, Excel files are binary content. You will need to convert such files or its data to textual based ones (txt, csv, xml, etc) in order to read it in memory with Python.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible: only files can ne opened (as of excel v2013). File mapped memory would have been an option if it were possible to choose where memory mapping starts, alas this does not appear possible.